# why doesn't list.end()-- decrement the iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator

so I'm trying to get the concept of Iterators.

```
int main()
{
    std::list<int> mylist;
    std::list<int>::iterator it1;
    std::list<int>::iterator it2;
    mylist.push_back(1);
    it1 = mylist.end()--;
    mylist.push_back(2);
    it2 = mylist.end();
    it2--;
    std::cout << "first: " << *it1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "second: " << *it2 << std::endl;
}
```

Outputs:

`first: 2
second: 2`

But I expected 1, 2. I've read that -- overloads the operator for iterators and "moves" the iterator to the left. So where exactly is the difference between `it1 = mylist.end()--;` and `it1 = mylist.end(); it1--;` ? Because `it1--;` returns the expected 1 and 2.

Comment: I think you are missing the difference between pre- and post- decrement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list member [end](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/end) function returns an iterator by value.

So in this snippet

```
it1 = mylist.end()--;
```

the post-increment operator is applied to the temporary returned by `.end()` *after* it's assigned to `it1`. So `it1` is exactly equal to `.end()`.

In the 2nd snippet

```
it2 = mylist.end();
it2--;
```

you are decrementing `it2` itself, so you are pointing to one position before `.end()`.